# Sentencia de insert no inserta nada a la BD y no muestra error

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo esta sentencia preparada para insertar datos, aunque los recibe y sale que se inserto no inserta nada en la base de Datos:

Echo de las variables:

```
 echo "<br>".$unidad;
 echo "<br>".$cedula1;
 echo "<br>".$cedula2;
 echo "<br>".$cedula3
 echo "<br>".$articulo_falta;
 echo "<br>".$aparte_falta;
 echo "<br>".$documentos_implode;
 echo "<br>".$fecha_inicio;
 echo "<br>".$fecha_termino;
 echo "<br>".$dias;
 echo "<br>".$aclaratoria;
 echo "<br>".$estado_sancion_id;
 echo "<br>".$tipo_medida;
 echo "<br>".$tipo_circunstancia;
 echo "<br>".$atenuantes_implode;
 echo "<br>".$agravantes_implode;
 echo "<br>".$total_demerito;
 echo "<br>".$lugar;
```

Datos de los Echo

```
033100000000
17739707
8644097
8644097
35
1
2-1
2017-03-23
2017-03-24
1
qwrqwrwq
1
2
40
3-4
0
6.55
2
```

Sentencia

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO sanciones (
      unidad,
      cedula_sancionado,
      cedula_sancionador, 
      cedula_superior, 
      articulo_falta, 
      aparte_falta, 
      documento_seleccion,
      fecha_inicio, 
      fecha_termino, 
      dias_sancion, 
      aclaratoria_sancion, 
      estado_sancion_id,
      medida_id,
      articulo_circunstancias,
      agravante_seleccion, 
      atenuante_seleccion, 
      total_demerito, 
      estado_lugar_id) 
      VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
var_dump($stmt);

$stmt->bind_param("siiiiisssisiiissdi"
 ,$unidad
 ,$cedula1
 ,$cedula2
 ,$cedula3
 ,$articulo_falta
 ,$aparte_falta
 ,$documentos_implode
 ,$fecha_inicio
 ,$fecha_termino
 ,$dias
 ,$aclaratoria
 ,$estado_sancion
 ,$tipo_medida
 ,$tipo_circunstancia
 ,$agravantes_implode
 ,$atenuantes_implode
 ,$total_demerito
 ,$lugar);
$stmt->execute();

var_dump($stmt);

if ($stmt){
echo ('<script>alert("OMD generada satisfactoriamente!");</script>');
/*echo ("<script>window.location = 'menu_unidades.php';</script>");*/
$stmt->close();
}else{
    echo ('<script>alert("No se pudo generar la OMD");</script>');
    echo ("<script>window.location = 'menu_generar_omd_unidades.php';</script>");
}
```

Sale "OMD generada satisfactoriamente" pero no inserta en la base de datos

Empezo a fallar cuando agregue $unidad a la insercion. la tabla tiene 19 campos (uno es el ID autoincremental)

El problema era que cuando la persona ingresaba algun dato este se ponia disabled, para evitar eso decidi clonar los campos de texto y al ser llenado un campo este obtenia su valor, resulta que varios valores INT se convertian a STRING procedi a multiplicar por 1 las variables

Ahora me da error el bind_param

Comment: ¿Cual es tu autoincremental? ¿Y ya verificaste si los datos que mandas coinciden con el tipo que recibe la BD

Comment: probe haciendo una insersion con un solo valor y si funciona

Comment: De que tipo es "unidad" en la base de datos? int o varchar?

Comment: es String y lo pasa string, ya he ido probando desde cero cada valor, lo raro es que este insertaba bien, incluso a pesar de que las cedulas no se multiplicaban por uno y el var_dump dijera que eran string las metia en la bd siendo INT estaas

Comment: el valor de $estado_sancion estaba vacio, no estaba pasando nada pues era $estado_sancion_id

Comment: Voté para el cierre de la pregunta como no relacionado. _El problema era que estaba asignando $estado_sancion y era $estado_sancion_id_

Comment: @A.Cedano Excelente :I (y) no hay problema

Comment: @A.Cedano, te invito a publicar tu comentario como respuesta, puedes optar por publicar como una respuesta _wiki (solo si así lo deseas)_. Si efectivamente tu comentario es la solución al problema del OP, considero que tu aporte debería ser mas visible (en una respuesta). Saludos.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Considero más bien que la mejor opción es el cierre ya que la causa del problema era un error ortográfico.

Comment: no puedo cerrarla como hago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que estaba asignando `$estado_sancion` y era `$estado_sancion_id`

Answer (score 2):

Prueba lo siguiente, devuelve un booleano:

```
if($stmt->execute()){
    //...
}else{
    //...
}
```

Comment: agregue eso y me dio error "No se pudo generar"

Comment: si escribo ese codigo genera 2 veces la insercion

Comment: La idea es poner ese código `en vez` del `$stmt->execute()` que tienes ahora. En segundo lugar, una vez que entra al "no se pudo generar", necesitas imprimir el error. Mira la función [mysqli::error](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php)